How to acess the parameters of Program Entity, TypeORM, Node.js, typescript?
I have 3 Tables : Program, Exam Setting, and Exam Schedule. I need to access the fields of Program in Exam Schedule service. The linking of the table is something like this : Program is linked with Exam Setting via programId, and Exam Setting is linked with Exam Schedule via examSettingId. The thing is I need to send these fields in the response to Frontend, where I will display these fields.I am providing relevant code snippets :-
//program entity

@Entity()
export class Program extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number

    @Column()
    name!: string

    @Column()
    desc!: string

    @Column({ length: 10 })
    abbreviation!: string

}

// exam setting entity

@Entity()
export class ExamSetting extends BaseEntity{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id! : number
    
    @Column()
    committeeId! : number

    @Column()
    programId! : number
          
    @Column()
    title! : string
    
    @Column()
    instructor! : string
    
}

// exam schedule entity

@Entity()
export class ExamSchedule extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    examSettingId!: number

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    branchId!: number

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    examCoordinator!: string

}

The function in Exam Schedule Service in which i need to access Program name.
// exam-schedule.service.ts

static async examScheduleDetail(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const id: any = req.params.id;
        const examScheduleData: ExamScheduleResponse = new ExamScheduleResponse();
        const examSchedule: ExamSchedule | null = await examScheduleRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });

        if (examSchedule != null) {
            const examSetting: ExamSetting | null = await examSettingRepository.findOneById(examSchedule.examSettingId);

            if (examSetting != null) {
                examScheduleData.id = examSchedule.id;
                examScheduleData.examSettingId = examSchedule.examSettingId;
                examScheduleData.branchId = examSchedule.branchId;
                examScheduleData.examCoordinator = examSchedule.examCoordinator;

                // Include ExamSetting properties in the response
                examScheduleData.examSettingTitle = examSetting.title;
                examScheduleData.examSettingInstructor = examSetting.instructor

                res.status(200).json({
                    error: false,
                    data: {
                        message: `Record fetched for id : ${examSchedule.id}`,
                        data: examScheduleData
                    }
                });
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({
                    error: true,
                    data: {
                        message: `No ExamSetting found for id : ${examSchedule.examSettingId}`
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                error: true,
                data: {
                    message: "No such record found."
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: true,
            data: {
                name: 'Internal Server Error',
                message: `${error}`
            }
        });
    }
}


What is your problem with the above code?

HI, I need to access parameters of Program using exam schedule service method that i provided above.
